# Showing a Wordpress Database custom table row column value from the database on button click

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, wordpress, coupon

I have added a custom table to the WordPress database. In addition to this, I have created a shortcode to be able to attach this to specific pages on my WordPress website. Table has two columns, **ID** and **coupon_code**.

The custom table is used to store coupon codes, and I need to be able to display the first row column value (coupon_code = *INSERT NUMBER*) from this table on a click event of a button.

```
function coupon_codes() {
 ?>
    <button class="reveal_coupon" onclick="reveal_coupon()">CLICK TO REVEAL 
COUPON CODE</button>
    <div class="coupon"></div>
      <?php
        global $wpdb;
        $result = $wpdb->get_results ( "SELECT * FROM coupon_codes LIMIT 1" 
        );
        foreach ( $result as $print )   {
          echo $print->coupon_code;
        }
}
add_shortcode( 'coupon_codes' , 'coupon_codes' );
```

I do understand that in order to achieve this, I need to move the PHP code into a separate PHP file, because this code is only run server-side and this can be achieved only if I run the file on a click event. That part I understand.

I cannot display the row value unless called with a click event. Which is why I think JS / jQuery would work for this case, but I am unable to figure out the script accurately to make it work.

Comment: Can you provide additional clarification? Why do you believe you need to move your PHP code into a separate file? This isn't necessarily true, and the code you've posted here looks like it would be viable. You "found similar examples but was unable to get it to show"... *what* were you unable to get to "show"?

Comment: Additionally, making multiple distinct inquiries in the same question is generally not best practice on Stack Overflow - you'd probably attract much better answers if you were to break out your second question regarding deletion of data from the Wordpress database into a separate question.

Comment: As far as I know, PHP is shown server-side, so the value would automatically be displayed in the shortcode if it exists. That is why I wanted to call it through a JS/jQuery script.

I was able to get the value to be displayed on the front-end, and it works, I am missing the show on click / delete first row component to make it work.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, esqew, I will move the second part into a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a misunderstanding of how the PHP and HTML/JS/CSS interact.

If you can't *display* the row value until a button click (which I'm assuming you have your `<button class="reveal_coupon"...` element for), you're almost on the right track here. Under the assumption that your `<div class="coupon"></div>` coupon is specifically to hold the coupon data output from your PHP script, there's a few observations I'll make:

- You're `echo`ing your data *outside* of your `coupon` `div`, so whatever you output won't necessarily be subject to the CSS styling and JS logic you've implented for this element. Move the PHP code between the `<div class="coupon">` and `</div>`.
- In order to achieve your desired functionality, you'll need to add your relevant JavaScript and CSS styles. The most maintainable way would be to break out your JS and CSS into separate files and utilize the [`wp_enqueue_script`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) and [`wp_enqueue_style`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/) functions in a new function/[enqueue](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/wp_enqueue_scripts) hooking pair to insert references to these files in the DOM at the appropriate times:

  ```
  add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'coupon_enqueue_scripts' );
  function coupon_enqueue_scripts() {
      wp_enqueue_script("coupon", "coupon.js");
  }

  add_action ( 'wp_enqueue_styles', 'coupon_enqueue_styles' );
  function coupon_enqueue_styles() {
      wp_enqueue_style("coupon", "coupon.css");
  }
  ```

  Within these files, you'd want to add (a) Javascript logic to implement the `reveal_coupon()` function referenced in your current HTML output, and (b) CSS styling to initially hide the coupon codes.

Comment: I was able to make it work with your suggestions, and done alterations. I appreciate your input and thank you kindly, esqew. I have extended the query and included a removal of the row after the end of the session, might need more work to allow removal of the row no matter if it is the first row or not, but I have all the pieces I was looking for. Thanks!